# Custom delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to know how can I use a custom delegate?

Comment: May be this is useful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095642/custom-delegate-example-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an example will help you:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol VSKeypadViewDelegate
@required
-(int)numberOfRows;
-(int)numberOfColumns;

-(NSString*)titleForButtonOnRow:(int)row andColumn:(int)column;
-(id)valueForButtonOnRow:(int)row andColumn:(int)column;
-(CGSize)sizeForButtonOnRow:(int)row andColumn:(int)column;
-(void)receivedValue:(id)value;
-(CGPoint)keypadOrigin;

@optional
-(NSArray *)additionalButtonsForKeypad;
//-(UIColor *)keypadBackgroundColor;
//-(UIColor *)keyBackgroundColorForRow:(int)row andColumn:(int)Column;
-(UIImage *)backgroundImageForState:(UIControlState)state forKeyAtRow:(int)row andColumn:(int)column;
-(BOOL)isButtonEnabledAtRow:(int)row andColumn:(int)column;

@end


@interface VSKeypadView : UIView {
    id<VSKeypadViewDelegate> delegate;
    NSArray *keypadButtons;
}

+ (VSKeypadView *)keypadViewWithFrame:(CGRect)r;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)r ;
-(void)fireKeypadButton:(id)sender;

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<VSKeypadViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

This is a keypad I wrote.
The VSKeyPadView derives from UIView and has a delegate ivar of type `id<VSKeypadViewDelegate>`, that means, that the object set to `delegate` is expected to conform to the protocol `VSKeypadViewDelegate`. That protocol has some required and some optional method. That means, that it is your responsibility to write those method — what ever makes sense for you.

You will find this code running in an example application at [github](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/KeyPad).